# Multiple CSS classes

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
input.bg:hover {

...

}
```

I'm using the above following: `<input type="submit" class="bg" value="ttttttt"/>`
now how to modify the class, so I can use `<input type="submit" class="bg-small" value="cccccccc"/>` ?

I need to add `.bg-small` into this css class, but I don't know how. I've been trying the following:

```
input.bg:hover .bg-small:hover {

...

}
```

Comment: This is a professional community; it's not fair to require the community members to clean up after you. If you can't refrain from the ALL CAPS and the txtspk, this might not be the place for you.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for editing that abomination into something readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.BG:hover, input.BG-SMALL:hover {

...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this ?

```
input.BG:hover, input.BG-SMALL:hover {
.....
}
```

So when you move your mouse over the normal input or submit input, they has the same effect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want the same class properties from BG for BG-SMALL, you can set

```
input.BG:hover, input.BG-SMALL:hover {
}
```

or just use the same class for the inputs if there's no difference.